# Icon remains after removal

Tags: icons, menu

I installed and removed the epic store through lutris. Unfortunately the icon remained. How do I remove it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

By using AppEditor can you delete/modify/add entries of slingshot. Open the terminal and type;

```
sudo apt install com.github.donadigo.appeditor
com.github.donadigo.appeditor
```

Or search the App Center for **appeditor**

Answer (score 0):

This happens also, when the application does not get removed completly. So you could check on the installed location and remove the rest of the data. This should end up where lutris / wine is installing applications. For me a test install ended up at /home//Games/

Answer (score 0):

If it is a wine application, you can find the "icon" (*.desktop) file into your home folder in the location `~/.local/share/applications/wine/Programs`.

1. Open your files application
2. Click on the home folder icon on the left
3. click once inside the address bar on the right in order to see the text address selected, then click to the right of the selected text to deselect it
4. Paste `/.local/share/applications/wine/Programs` next to the home folder adress and hit enter.

If it is not a wine application, the location should be `~/.local/share/applications/` or `/usr/share/applications/`, keep in mind that in order to manipulate the files into the second one you have to use **New Window As Administrator** right click option to start the Files app.